# How do I add my own icon for my magento site?

Tags: favicons

I created my own icon for my website that I want to use.  I hate having that Magento logo for my site.  How do I do it?

Comment: Do you mean a FAVicon?

Answer (score 1):

if it is for magento  1 version ,

Log into your Magento Admin Panel.

Go to

```
System > Configuration > Design(in the left side menu) > Header.
```

Change the file name in the "Logo Image Src" to the file name you just uploaded.

Leave the images/prefix alone.

Click "Save Config"

you can find more information in below links :

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/102-customizing-magento/changing-the-logo-in-magento

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/design/logo-upload.html

https://pagayo.com/blog/how-to-change-logo-in-magento

for magento 2 version , below link :

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-upload-logo-magento-2.html